# Google Drive API webhook returning change resources in wrong order

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a webhook setup with the Google Drive API, and it works for almost everything except when a file is deleted. It seems as though I always get 2/3 webhook notifications when a file changes, which isn't a problem.

When I delete a file however, those 2 notifications mess things up. They come out of order (i.e. change resource 989 comes before 999), and the new one comes first, invalidating the older change resource.

To explain, here are two post I received on my webhook, chronologically ordered.

This one has a good webhook, but the resource id in the param is 899.
[image: **First post, note higher change resource id:**]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/il3co.png

Now this one comes in after, which is has a param of 898, but I cannot use.
[image: **Second post, not lower change id, gets invalidated:**]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg7SE.png

This last one most likely has the delete call I need, but cannot access.

Is this something I have to handle? Or is it something from google's side in terms of async calls?